# How do I extract only alphabet from a alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string "5A" or "a6". I want to get only "A" or "a" on the result. I am using the following but it's not working.

Javascript

```
 var answer = '5A';
 answer = answer.replace(/^[0-9]+$/i);
 //console.log(answer) should be 'A';
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
 var answer = '5A';
 answer = answer.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
```

`g` for global, no `^` or `$`, and `''` to replace it with nothing. Leaving off the second parameter replaces it with the string `'undefined'`.

I wondered if something like this this might be faster, but it and variations are much slower:

```
function alphaOnly(a) {
    var b = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'z') b += a[i];
    }
    return b;
}
```

http://jsperf.com/strip-non-alpha

Comment: What was added here is the `g` flag which stands for global

Answer (score 35):

```
let answer = '5A';
answer = answer.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
// [^a-z] matches everything but a-z
// the flag `g` means it should match multiple occasions
// the flag `i` is in case sensitive which means that `A` and `a` is treated as the same character ( and `B,b`, `C,c` etc )
```

Instead of `a-z` then you can use `\p{L}` and the `/u` modifier which will match any letter, and not just a though z, for instance:

```
'50Æ'.replace(/[^\p{L}]/gu, ''); // Æ
// [^\p{L}] matches everything but a unicode letter, this includes lower and uppercase letters
// the flag `g` means it should match multiple occasions
// the flag `u` will enable the support for unicode character classes.
```

See https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_unicode for support

Comment: This is very elegant. It is funny that sometimes the best answer is almost the latest. This is the only answer that is both always* correct and simple .

*It is true that the user asked to find letters in specific strings with only number(s) and no spaces or other, but yet one may run this on "B f,.7945 a" and get "B f,. a" instead of a probably more desired "Bfa". So I consider this answer much more prompt to never deceive. With respect to other good answers around.

Answer (score 5):

```
var answer = '5A';
answer = answer.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
```

You can also do it without a regular expression if you care about performance ;)

You code hade multiple issues:

- `string.replace` takes tow parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
- the flag `i`, standing for `case insensitive`, doesn't make sense since you are dealing with numbers (what's an upper-case 1?!)
- `/^[0-9]+$/` would only match a number, nothing more. You should check this out: http://www.regexper.com/. Enter your regex (without the slashes) in the box and hit enter!

In general I would advice you to learn a bit about basic regular expressions. Here is a useful app to play with them: http://rubular.com/

Comment: Please link [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) because of [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Oriol I love MDN, no worries, I just picked the first link I found and the description of the parameters is correct; it's everything I needed to show

Comment: @Aegis, every link helps them stay up top in Google.

Comment: @Oriol, ironically, you linked to the wicked site!

Comment: @TrevorDixon Haha, it was intentional to help people compare both documents and discover MDN is much more complete.

Answer (score 4):

The way you asked, you want to find the letter rather than remove the number (same thing in this example, but could be different depending on your circumstances) - if that's what you want, there's a different path you can choose:

```
var answer = "5A";
var match = answer.match(/[a-zA-Z]/);
answer = match ? match[0] : null;
```

It looks for a match on the letter, rather that removing the number. If a match is found, then `match[0]` will represent the first letter, otherwise `match` will be null.

Answer (score 3):

**JavaScript:**
It will extract all Alphabets from any string..

```
     var answer = '5A';
         answer = answer.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

```js
/*var answer = '5A';
     answer = answer.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');*/
$("#check").click(function(){
$("#extdata").html("Extraxted Alphabets : <i >"+$("#data").val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')+"</i>");
});
```

```css
i{
color:green;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="text" id="data">
  <button id="check">Click To Extract</button><br/>
  <h5 id="extdata"></h5>
  
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to post another answer that brings nothing new to the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a bit @TrevorDixon's and @Aegis's answers using `\d` (digit) instead of `[0-9]`

```
 var answer = '5A';
 answer = answer.replace(/\d/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = '5A';
answer.replace(/\W/g,"").replace(/\d/g,"")
```

Comment: The question already assumes the string is alphanumeric. The `\W` doesn't do anything.