# How can i convert a given string to camel case using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function toCamelCase(str) {
    // Convert the entire string to lowercase
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
        // For each match, convert the first character of the match to uppercase
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    }).replace(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, ''); // Remove any non-alphanumeric characters from the beginning of the string
}
```

I have been trying this code. But the problem is if the provided string is with a number or has any other character that should be removed. I couldn't build this logic. Can anyone explain how can i do this?  ***[tag:I have seen some solution but that can not filter the number.]***

Comment: (/^[^a-zA-Z]+/, '') update your second replace with this and your code work as expected.

Comment: "*if the provided string is with a number or has any other character that should be removed*" [How do I extract only alphabet from a alphanumeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18624457) | [javascript regex to return letters only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23136947)

Comment: **Converts a given string to camel case by removing non-alphanumeric characters (except letters and numbers).**
[https://jsfiddle.net/tpmjns1o/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/tpmjns1o/6/)